# Are there any female trinities in Hinduism?

Tags: gods, goddess

Every Hindu is well aware of (male) trinities, but I have also heard that there are female trinities too.

Is that correct?

Comment: loosely, one can say that Laskshmi, Saraswati and Parvati are female trinity, but all of them are considered part of Shakti.

Comment: Make this comment as a better answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can view *Lakshmi*, *Saraswati*, and *Parvati* (*Kali*) as the female trinity.

They are the wives/female counterparts of *Vishnu*, *Brahma* and *Shiva*, respectively.

<sup>[Reference](http://www.bellaterreno.com/art/a_religion/hindu/hinduismgods_trinity_goddesses.aspx)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The male trinity is essentially incomplete without a female trinity.
**The female trinity comprises of Saraswati, Laxmi and Shakti who are the consorts of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva respectively.**

- Saraswati embodies knowledge (needed by Brahma to create)
- Laxmi embodies wealth (needed by Vishnu to sustain)
- Shakti embodies power (needed by Shiva to destroy)

The three Goddesses are seen as one entity and together called **Devi, [Tridevi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridevi) or Adi-Maya-Shakti or [Adi Parashakti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Parashakti)**